# Do I need to import AWS SDK into lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, amazon-ses

Might be a dumb question, but couldn't find a clear answer on stack/aws docs. My assumption is that it should be built in to lambda.

I am running Node10.x, with Axios module, in AWS Lambda. I have a successful function which checks a DNS/EC2/Endpoint pathway and returns the proper response. I want to automate it so it checks, lets say...every 10 minutes. It will notify me in SES if there is an error, and do nothing if its a good response.

All the functionality works, except I am having trouble getting SES integrated. inside the if statement below, i have added this code, the console.log works, so its just the SES part im having issues with.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let ses = new aws.SES({
   region: 'us-east-1'
});

let data = "document_contents=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><auth><user>fake</user><pass>info</pass></auth>";

var axios = require("axios");

var config = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' },
};

let res = await axios.post('https://awebsiteidontwanttogiveout.com', data, config);
let eParams;

if (res.status === 200) {
  console.log("Success");

  eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["banana@apples.com"]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: "Test SUCCESSFUL"
                }
            },
            Subject: {Test SUCCESSFUL"
            }
        },
        Source: "banana@apples.com"
  };

  ses.sendEmail(eParams);
} 

if (res.status != 200) {
  console.log("Failure");

  eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ["banana@apples.com"]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: "Test FAIL"
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: "Test FAIL"
            }
        },
        Source: "banana@apples.com"
  };

  ses.sendEmail(eParams);
}


};
```

I'm getting a time out after 3 seconds. I uploaded a zip file to node, with dependencies. do I need to install AWS SDK and upload that with the file? shouldn't it be built in somehow? am I missing something in my SES call?

thanks

Comment: Not sure, but should you also `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');` and `var ses= new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'});` etc?

Comment: i do have those in there, this is just the part of the function where i test and attempt to send the email

Comment: what exactly did upload in the zip file? is there a node_modules folder in there?

Comment: Neil, have you ever uploaded a zip to lambda, its a pretty cool option. You take the files in your directory (for example i use Visual studio code). i have the index.js file and then i run npm install axios. npm creates the dependencies, then i zip that folder and my index.js from the root. the Lambda has a option to upload a zip. if i needed to add the AWS SDK, i would install it this way. YES THERE IS A NODE_MODULES

Comment: to be clear, the imported modules work, as i had axios running successfully and giving me a verification response. just need to know if i need a AWS SDK in there.

Comment: aws-sdk does not need to be imported, it is already included within the lambda runtime

Comment: i thought so LostJon. Any ideas about my code, ill update to include the whole function

Comment: hard to say w/o knowing network constraints. is there a corporate proxy you have to go through? the only other is that you should use `await ses.sendEmail(eParams).promise()` as this call is asynchronous

Comment: i will try await. its going thru a route 53 DNS, then thru an EC2 reverse proxy server, then to an Oracle server

Comment: are you sure its the `sendEmail` function thats problematic?

Comment: pretty sure as the fucntion, ifs, and console.logs work. until i added the SDK stuff everything was fine. adding the eParams and ses.sendEmail broke it

Comment: smells like a proxy issue, but i cant tell

Comment: proxy works very smooth. the axios call is thru the proxy. works good from everywhere i call it. Nginx, strong as bull, haha. the AWS SES stuff is where the issue is.

Comment: you ahvent configured a proxy for AWS tho. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html

Comment: thank you, didn't know i had to d that. I had the role, policy configured, thought that it would take it from there. will try that out

Comment: is your email is verified on SES

Comment: yes email is verified, good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues to address:

1. sendEmail is an async function from AWS SDK, you have to use:

`await  ses.sendEmail(eParams).promise()`

or else, Lambda would end execution before `sendEmail method` completes.

2. Lambda's default timeout is 3 seconds. This can be increased to a max of 15 minutes in the Lambda configuration.

[image]